# JavaScript doesn't load first time on new window

Tags: javascript, google-picker

I got a html file that has the google picker api implemented following the tutorial (https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)

I'm opening that html file in a new window, by clicking a button that calls windows.open()

But somehow, the first time I open it, nothing shows. I have to close the window, and click again on the button that opens it.

Any help?

Comment: Post your code as part of the body of your question. Probably something to do with how you're handling the load event, or positioning of script tags, but impossible to say without seeing your code.

Comment: please provide a fiddle to show your code.

Comment: Post your code as part of the body of your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The pastebin code you provided is not helping so I just made you an example.

**openwindow.html**

```
//HTML page with a button that opens the googlepicker.html
<body>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<FORM> 
//fill in your appropriate URL
<INPUT type="button" value="New Window!" onClick="window.open('http://localhost:8000/googlepicker.html','window name','width=400,height=400')"> 
</FORM>
</body>
```

**googlepicker.html**

Use the code from [Google Picker sample](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
  var developerKey = 'xxxxxxxYYYYYYYY-12345678';

  // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
  var clientId = "1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com"

  // Scope to use to access user's photos.
  var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];

  var pickerApiLoaded = false;
  var oauthToken;

  // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
  function onApiLoad() {
    gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
    gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
  }

  function onAuthApiLoad() {
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
          'client_id': clientId,
          'scope': scope,
          'immediate': false
        },
        handleAuthResult);
  }

  function onPickerApiLoad() {
    pickerApiLoaded = true;
    createPicker();
  }

  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
      createPicker();
    }
  }

  // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
  function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
          addView(google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS).
          setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
          setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
          setCallback(pickerCallback).
          build();
      picker.setVisible(true);
    }
  }

  // A simple callback implementation.
  function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = 'nothing';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
      url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
    }
    var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
  }
</script>
```

```
<!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
```

When you click the button, it will open a window to googlepicker.html. Hope that helps.